# Bootstrap Full-width Row With Photo & Text On Each Side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, row, photo, responsive

I'd like to have a row with a photo taking the full width & height of the column, with a paragraph to it's side - As shown below. I can't seem to get the hang of it, especially when the screen becomes smaller/mobile everything gets messed up.

Can anyone please guide me?

[image]

There is a working example I came across here: http://kallyas.net/demo/ scroll down to "truly multi purpose".

My code:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="img-box">
                <img src="images/about2.jpg" alt="about" class="img-responsive">
            </div><!-- end img box -->      
            </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8">
     <div id="about-text">
             <p id="demo">Malta 5D  is a new generation theatre where you feel the “real” emotions of the movie. In a short time, you may explore the colourful and impressive episodes of the Maltese history and culture, magnified with 3D film, moving seats, water spray, air blasts and leg ticklers.  A unique experience for all ages!  An exhibition of works by local artists will be on display in the foyer.</p>
       </div><!-- end about text-->

  </div><!-- end col -->
</div><!-- end row -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Check demo **[here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/mApZmy?editors=1100)**

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row row-height">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-custom pr0">
    <div class="img-box">
      <img src="http://agrofields.cmsmasters.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bg-03.jpg" alt="about" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <!-- end img box -->
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8 col-custom">
    <div id="about-text">
      <p id="demo">Malta 5D is a new generation theatre where you feel the “real” emotions of the movie. In a short time, you may explore the colourful and impressive episodes of the Maltese history and culture, magnified with 3D film, moving seats, water spray, air
        blasts and leg ticklers. A unique experience for all ages! An exhibition of works by local artists will be on display in the foyer.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end about text-->

  </div>
  <!-- end col -->
</div>
<!-- end row -->
```

CSS:

```
.row-height {
  display: flex;
}

.pr0 {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.col-custom {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.img-box {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-box img {
  object-fit: cover
}
```

Comment: Thanks however this causes the photo to become unproportionate and stretched on resize, and at smaller screen sizes the paragraph gets longer than the image and it does not remain at full height and causes empty space under it.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks it is quite what I wanted. I hid the div/image once the screen size got smaller than 700px as it looked weird, apart from that it looks and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement the following would be to use the *vh* or "view height" attribute in css.

For an example if the class added to the image div is 'image'. The code would be as follows:

```
.image{
    height:100vh;
}
```

Obviously its position would be relative to the webpage hence a better updated code snippet to go with this would give a better idea.

Comment: This too caused the image to become stretched, I've added my own code.